# DJANGO - Ficheros estaticos - Error 404

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Estoy empezando los cimientos de mi proyecto Django y en varias pruebas de las estructuras no me relaciona los estáticos en una template.

Decir que está ejecutándose sobre *runserver* y por el momento, el unico problema que me he encontrado es a la hora de meter los estilos.

He intentado varias fórmulas pero no doy con la tecla...

Rutas:

- **Proyecto** : .../www/django/proyecto
- **APP**:       .../www/django/proyecto/core/
- **Template**:  .../www/django/proyecto/core/templates/core/
- **Estaticos**: .../www/django/proyecto/core/static/core/
- **CSS**:       .../www/django/proyecto/core/static/core/css/

Settings:

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

el base.html de la template:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} | Juan Perez (Ingeniero)</title>
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
</head>
```

el fichero de la template:

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block title %}Mi Web{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <h2>Mi Web Personal</h2>
  <p>Bienvenidos.</p>
{% endblock %}
```

El fichero CSS:

```
h1 a, h2 a {
     color: #C25100;
}
body {
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

Resultado :

[image: Resultado en web]

```
[24/Nov/2021 13:51:38] "GET /home/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1041
[24/Nov/2021 13:51:38] "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 179
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado la solución y la pongo para posibles futuras dudas.

El problema estaba en la variable BASE_DIR en el settings.py:

```
Import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Con esto se ha solucionado sin modificar nada mas fe los datos proporcionados.

Answer (score 0):

El error esta que en el settings se establece que la url de los archivos estaticos esta en '/static/', y los archivos estaticos vos los tenes en la carpeta core.

Lo que debes hacer es, mover la carpeta static hacia el directorio raiz del proyecto.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta.

Me temo que no, he probado varias combinaciones a raiz de la carpeta core/static...tanto en estructura como en el fichero html hacia donde está apuntando y nada..

Comment: Edito la respuesta con una posible solucion!

Comment: Gracias, en cuanto tenga acceso a la máquina, es de trabajo lo pruebo y público resultado. Gracias!